# How can XAML Islands follow the system theme change?

Tags: windows, xaml, winapi, xaml-islands

I'm developing a Win32 native application using XAML Islands.
I notice that the XAML controls will not follow the change of system color theme.
e.g. I change from 'light' to 'dark' in Settings, the controls still remain in light mode.
How can I make them follow the theme change?

Comment: The [UISettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings) class exposes a number of events, like [UISettings::ColorValuesChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.colorvalueschanged). The documentation doesn't state, whether this type can be used in a classic Desktop application. You'd have to try and see.

Comment: @IInspectable UISettings class is accessible. But the matter is how to set the changed theme for XAML Islands. XamlWindowManager and DesktopWindowXamlSource do not provide a property to set theme globally, and enumerating the controls and change their related properties do not sound a good idea.

Comment: Can you change the default MRT context? [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcecontext.qualifiervalues).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT  ResourceContext::GetForCurrentView() will fail in Win32.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcecontext.getforviewindependentuse#Windows_ApplicationModel_Resources_Core_ResourceContext_GetForViewIndependentUse

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT It also fails, unfortunately.